# Setting NSTextField.isSelectable to true not working

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

In the following code, I have an NSTextField, and I want it to be selectable. However, doing `NSTextFieldInstance.isSelectable = true` doesn't seem to work, as the NSTextField is still not selectable.

Below is the actual code:

```
import Cocoa

class AppController: NSObject {
    @IBOutlet weak var feedbackLabel: NSTextField?
    @IBAction func pressedIncorrect(_ sender: Any?) {
        feedbackLabel?.stringValue = "Incorrect!";
    }
    @IBAction func pressedCorrect(_ sender: Any?) {
        feedbackLabel?.stringValue = "Correct!";
    }
    override init() {
        feedbackLabel?.isSelectable = true;
    }
}
```

What am I doing incorrectly? How can I successfully make my `feedbackLabel` selectable in this application?

Comment: Why don't you set that in xib/storyboard. Is setting `isEditable` making any difference?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your feedbackLabel?.isSelectable, chances are the code is either not executed at all (if loaded from a Xib/Storyboard) or the feedbackLabel has not yet been initialized and is nil when that code executes.

Comment: Do `pressedIncorrect` and `pressedCorrect` work? Do you want to select the text field (blue focus ring) or the text in the text field (and copy)?

Comment: @Willeke they do work, and I want the feedback text in the label (which either says "Correct!" or "Incorrect!") to be selectable (blue highlight and copy). The label does change if the corresponding button is clicked. The program works 100% as intended EXCEPT that the feedback label isn't selectable, and I want it to be.

Comment: Is `feedbackLabel` `nil` in `init()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a property called editable and the difference between them that editable means A Boolean that controls whether the user can edit the receiver’s text.
but selectable means A Boolean that determines whether the receiver is selectable (but not editable).
by apple documentation